# Is there any way that I can use .find() method to JSON return file?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a query from users' location + users' pick on the category list. Since the $geoNear is not accepting two parameters. I've been trying to do a query from the return value. However, I am getting an error saying that I can't do .find() to a JSON format file (not a function).

```
  static async getuserinitialplace(favCatgories, userCoordinates) {
    console.log(userCoordinates);
    try {
      const places = await Place.aggregate([
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: userCoordinates },
            distanceField: 'calcDistance',
            maxDistance: 25000,
            spherical: true,
          },
        },
        { $limit: 200 },
      ]);
      return places;
    } catch (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

I'd also tried to put it inside of the function, then I get a callback error + others.

```
 static async getuserinitialplacea(req, res) {
    const result = await PlaceService.getuserinitialplacea(
      JSON.parse(req.query.userCoordinates),
    ).find({category: req.query.favCatgories})
    res.send(result)
  }
```

Is there anyway that I can query with two parameters when I use $geoNear?

Answer (score 1):

Try to write both args for a `getuserinitialplace` in a variable and then use it them as args, like this:

```
 static async getuserinitialplacea(req, res) {
   try {
    let arg = JSON.parse(req.query.userCoordinates);
    const result = await PlaceService.getuserinitialplace(arg)
    res.send(result)
   } catch (e) {
     console.error(e)
   }
  }
```

Also this `.find({category: req.query.favCatgories})` find part doesn't make sence. Aggregation [doesn't return you a Mongoose Document or a Mongoose Model](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model.aggregate).

If your should be used as a second argument if your function, then use it, like this:

```
    let arg = JSON.parse(req.query.userCoordinates);
    let another_arg = req.query.favCatgories;
    const result = await PlaceService.getuserinitialplace(arg, another_arg )
```

or even better:

```
/** Code */
const { userCoordinates, favCatgories} = req.query;
const result = await PlaceService.getuserinitialplace(favCatgories, userCoordinates)
/** Other code */
```

And if your want to find something after `$geoNear` stage, just add another stage with `$match` and query it. Like this:

```
  static async getuserinitialplace(favCatgories, userCoordinates) {
    console.log(userCoordinates);
    try {
      const places = await Place.aggregate([
        {
          $geoNear: {
            near: { type: 'Point', coordinates: userCoordinates },
            distanceField: 'calcDistance',
            maxDistance: 25000,
            spherical: true,
          },
        },
        /** You could also add it before $geoNear stage */
        { $match: { nameOfField: favCatgories } },
        /** OR { $match: favCatgories  }, */
        /** BUT favCatgories should be an object */
        { $limit: 200 },
      ]);
      return places;
    } catch (err) {
      return console.log(err);
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I'd tried that though. as soon as I add 'favCategories' to 'static async getuserinitialplace(favCategories, userCoordinates)', the error pops out :/